# How to handle JSON in a Kafka topic?

Tags: json, serialization, apache-kafka

I'm building a Java application in which there are some ***JSON*** objects (in particular AnyJson objects from com.satori.rtm.model.AnyJson) and I want to send these objects in a **Kafka** Topic. Should I send them in AnyJson o String type? I'm asking this because the constructor `KafkaProducer<K, V>` seems to have some problem to handle JSON values when (de)serialization.

This in my producer configuration

```
Properties props= new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBrokerEndpoint);
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaProducer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
kafkaProducer= new KafkaProducer<Integer, AnyJson>(props);
```

where *JsonSerializer.class* is from *org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;*
I have seen there are multiple packages that handle the JSON objects (as *kafka.utils.json, com.google.gson.JsonObject*;, etc).
Then when running

```
ProducerRecord<Integer, AnyJson> record= new ProducerRecord<Integer, AnyJson>(topic, json);
kafkaProducer.send(record);
```

I have the following exception
**No serializer found for class com.satori.rtm.connection.GsonSerializer$JsonElementWrapper**

Any help?

Comment: You can use String SerDes, sure. But what problems are you seeing? Please [edit] your question to include the code as a [mcve] and errors. For example, are you using `KafkaProducer<AnyJson, AnyJson>`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated the question

Comment: You need to use Jackson library with the Spring Kafka package. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonDeserializer.java

Comment: I have the dependency for spring `
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Yes, I know. I am pointing out you need Jackson for JSON, not Gson, which is what `com.satori.rtm.model.AnyJson` is using

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer` for key and value serializations.
Now you should configure your producer record with byte[].

Then use [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) from Jackson (http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial ) to convert any json object to byte array.